# Get %{key,value} from list of map

Tags: elixir

I have list with nested map

```
[ %{
    "name" => "sam",
    "p" => [
      %{
        "amount" => "$10",
      }
    ],
    "group" => "a",   
},   
%{
    "name" => "lisa",
    "p" => [
      %{
        "amount" => "$20",
      }
    ],
    "group" => "a",   
}, 
 %{
    "name" => "joe",
    "p" => [
      %{
        "amount" => "$30",
      }
    ],
    "group" => "b",   
} ]
```

I have to loop through the list to get the `name` as well `amount` from the list in such a way that if group is `a` then retrieve the `amount` , otherwise put `nil` to the map. So that the final list can look like

```
[
  %{name: "sam",amount: "$10"},
  %{name: "lisa", amount: "$20"},
  %{name: "joe", amount: nil}
]
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map your elements, hence `Enum.map/2` with different function clauses matching different cases seems to be the best fit.

```rb
Enum.map(data, fn
  %{"group" => "a", "name" => name, "p" => [%{"amount" => amount}]} ->
    %{name: name, amount: amount}

  %{"name" => name} ->
    %{name: name, amount: nil}
end)
#⇒[
#   %{amount: "$10", name: "sam"},
#   %{amount: "$20", name: "lisa"},
#   %{amount: nil, name: "joe"}
# ]
```

Comment: Nice. It's not so obvious, but yes logical, that you can simple present differ argument forms in a space separated list - like that.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff well, thanks to multiple function clauses I finally have a proof of my lovely 1st commandment _“if you find yourself using a conditional `if` statement, you are doing it wrong.”_ :)